# Maven layout Structure creation. Only resource folder is visible, no Java folder created

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

Hi I am quite new in maven. I have started to create a maven web application project using eclipse kepler. `src/main/resource` is created but `src/main/java` not created. I don't know where I have to do the coding (put my Java files) and where i have to put the property file. Please help me to do project in  maven.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to look the following link.

http://fruzenshtein.com/setup-of-dynamic-web-project-using-maven/